# Integrate Thrift Server into existing app in non blocking mode

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, thrift

i need to integrate a thrift server into an existing app, so i need to startup it into my application startup method but when i cal serve() method, of any thrift server class, it doesn't return and let run the services.
I'm wondering what is the way to use thrift service into an application thread.

thank in advanced

Comment: it's how any server is supposed to work: it waits for incoming requests from your clients

Comment: i'm not agree, i can have many kind of  services in my middle layer, i think that there i way to punt server in another thread

Answer (score 0):

You could either use [Asynchronous Thrift](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1) or Thrift over http which we use.

Comment: Hi thank you for replay, i have resolved using msgpack-rpc with msgpack serialization. It's more versatile for create server layer. IN my project i have choice to use a different serialization method and i use(msgpack, thirft, or protobuff only for rpc system)